# SQL - Getting multiple counts with criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables that store customers, customer visits to a store, and store reviews:

**Customers**
ID
BirthDate...etc.

**CustomerVisits**
Customer_ID
Store_ID
VisitDate

**Reviews**
Store_ID
Customer_ID
Rating

What I need to get in a (hopefully) a single SQL statement is a count of all time visitors per store, count of visitors within the last 30 days per store, average customer age per store, and average review score per store. I need to be able to do this for several stores at once using an IN clause like where Store_ID IN (1,2,3). I know I could create a temp table and loop through store_ids, running multiple selects, but would rather do this in a single select if that is possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could perform each count in a subquery as follows:

```
SELECT  Stores.Store_ID,
        review.AvgRating,
        cv.VisitsLast20days,
        cv.TotalVisits,
        cv.AvgCustomerAge
FROM    Stores
        LEFT JOIN
        (   SELECT  Store_ID, [AvgRating] = AVG(Rating)
            FROM    Reviews
            GROUP BY Store_ID
        ) review
            ON review.Store_ID = Stores.Store_ID
        LEFT JOIN
        (   SELECT  CustomerVisits.Store_ID,
                    [VisitsLast30Days] = COUNT(CASE WHEN CustomerVisits.VisitDate >= DATEADD(DAY, -30, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) THEN 1 END),
                    [TotalVisits] = COUNT(*),
                    [AvgCustomerAge] = AVG(DATEDIFF(DAY, Customer.BirthDate, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) / 365.25
            FROM    CustomerVisits
                    INNER JOIN Customer
                        ON Customer.Customer_ID = CustomerVisits.Customer_ID
            GROUP BY CustomerVisits.Store_ID
        ) cv
            ON cv.Store_ID = Stores.Store_ID;
```

I have assumed you have a table called stores to do this, and used LEFT JOINs on the assumption that not every store has a visit or a review.

I've also used a fairly crude method of calculating the average age of a customer, but given it is only for an average, and not actually working out an accurate age for an individual I doubt it will adversely affect the results

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select s.Store_ID,
       count(distinct v.Customer_ID) all_time_visitors,
       count(distinct case when datediff(d, v.VisitDate, getdate()) <= 30 then v.Customer_ID end) 30day_visitors,
       avg(datediff(yy, c.BirthDate, getdate())) avg_customer_age,
       max(r.avg_rating) avg_rating
from Stores s
left join CustomerVisits v on s.Store_ID = v.Store_ID
left join Customers c on v.Customer_ID = c.Customer_ID
left join (select Store_ID, avg(Rating) avg_rating
           from Reviews
           group by Store_ID) r on s.Store_ID = r.Store_ID
where s.Store_ID in (1,2,3) /*amend as required*/
group by s.Store_ID
```

Comment: 'Y' is shorthand for `DAYOFYEAR`, not `YEAR`, so the avg_customer_age here would be in days.

Comment: @GarethD: D'oh! Thanks - I have amended the query accordingly.